# Drag scrolling on web

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

how to make scrolling like this: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devices/blackberrypearl.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the source of their webpage, it looks like they're using this [overscroll](http://azoffdesign.com/overscroll) plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Overscroll didn't work well for me on the iPad.  Here are some more options:

- [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)
- [TouchScroll](http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/09/15/touchscroll-0-2-first-alpha-available/)
- [jScrollTouch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jScrollTouch)